# java sql time stamp in UTC 0 date part coming wrong

Tags: java, java-8

I am using following code for getting current system time which needed to be passed to some sql queries

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
long t = date.getTime();
java.sql.Timestamp sqlTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(t);

log.info("Current Time:" + sqlTimestamp.toString());
```

Now i also needed to get UTC 0 time (not GMT 0)

log.info("Current Time:" + sqlTimestamp.toString());

**Current Time:2019-01-04 15:04:50.735**

I am trying following code but it looks like not getting date part correctly

```
 log.info("Current UTC Time:" + new java.sql.Timestamp(Instant.now().atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toEpochSecond()).toString());
```

**Current UTC Time:1970-01-19 02:36:36.299**

Please let me know what correction i needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use DateTimeFormatter

```
sqlTimestamp.toInstant().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
```

Comment: May as well simply use `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)` instead of the `sqlTimestamp.toInstant...` part. Anyway, your pattern is incorrect and should be `"uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`.

Comment: TiiJ7 i will try it as well. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are using `toEpochSecond()` instead `toEpochMilli()`

Javadoc for your `Timestamp` constructor

> Timestamp(long time) Constructs a Timestamp object using a **milliseconds** time value.

So you can use `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()` as `Instant.now()` will return you `Instant` in UTC

(And of course, avoid using old date API if possible, use new date API from JDK8)

Comment: `Instant.now().atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toEpochSecond()` to `Instant.now().atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toEpochMilli()`

Comment: log.info("Current UTC Time:" + new java.sql.Timestamp(Instant.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC ).toEpochMilli()).toString());

not compiling

Comment: Sorry - `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()`

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Use the modern *java.time* classes instead.

```
Instant
.now()
.toString()
```

> 2019-01-23T01:23:45.123456789Z

## java.time

You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago entirely by the *java.time* classes.

Capture the current moment.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Generate text to represent that moment in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

If the `T` in the middle bothers you, replace it. But I encourage you to stick with the strict ISO 8601 format for logging.

```
String outputModified = output.replace( "T" , " " ) ;
```

> get UTC 0 time (not GMT 0)

UTC is the same thing as GMT, practically speaking, for common business-oriented apps.

Comment: both lines giving same time 


log.info("Current Time:" + sqlTimestamp.toString());

log.info("Current UTC Time:" + new java.sql.Timestamp(Instant.now().toEpochMilli()).toString());

Comment: As per your suggestion I can do "T" replacement and Z replacement but wanted to know if there is some built in api exists in java. I am mainly a .net developer but doing some correction in some legacy java code

Comment: @KamranShahid No, no, stop using `Timestamp` and `Date` at all. Never touch those classes again. They are have many problems and bloody awful design. Forget about them, and `Calendar` & `SimpleDateFormat`. Use only classes from the *java.time* packages. To interoperable with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, use the new conversion methods added to the old classes.

Comment: You should always keep the `Z` as it indicates UTC.  Without an indicator of offset-from-UTC or time zone, the text loses its meaning. For example, a twelve o’clock value could mean noon in Tokyo, noon in Kolkata, noon in Casablanca, or noon in Montréal, all very different moments. But if you insist, convert to an `OffsetDateTime` and use a `DateTimeFormatter` to suppress the display of the offset. But this would be a poor practice.

Comment: @KamranShahid  Tip: for .Net, check out the port of *java.time* predecessor *Joda-Time* in the *Noda Time* project.

Comment: legacy code dear. no prepare statement. date time is passing in string and working :)

Answer (score 1):

First avoid the classes `Date` and `Timestamp`. Instead of `Timestamp` pass a modern type from java.time to your SQL query. Depending on the details of your JDBC driver and the requirements of your query use either `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime` with an offset of UTC (zero) or `LocalDateTime`.

The `Date` and `Timestamp` classes have design issues and are long outdated. The `Timestamp` class can be very confusing, and there doesn’t seem to be agreement whether to interpret it as a timestamp (as the name says) or as a date and time of day. Fortunately since JDBC 4.2 you don’t need `Timestamp` anymore.

For example:

```
    OffsetDateTime currentUtcTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
            "select col1 from your_table where your_timestamp > ?;");
    ps.setObject(1, currentUtcTime);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```